# Xcode 8.0 and Swift 3.0 conversion: Looking for explanation for a particular conversion error

Tags: swift, swift3, nsnumber, xcode8, numberformatter

I am a little confused about a conversion error.

I migrated my project form Swift 2.3 to Swift 3.0

```
    func updateCelsiusLabel() {

    if let value = celsiusValue {

        //This was the original code (that worked but is) failing after migration 
        //due to: Argument labels do not match any available overloads
        celsiusLabel.text = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value))


        //This is my code trying to fix this issue and the project is now compiling 
        //and everything is fine
         celsiusLabel.text = numberFormatter.string(from: value as NSNumber)

    }
    else { celsiusLabel.text = "???"
    }
}
```

At first I thought that in Swift 3.0 the cast `Type(value)` was now forbidden, but I checked and I get absolutely no compiler warning. Can somebody tell me what the problem with `NSNumber(value)` is?

As far as I understand `value as NSNumber` and `NSNumber(value)` should be the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Swift 3, `NSNumber(value)` won't work. Let's say that your value is an Int. In that case, you'd need `NSNUmber(value: yourIntValue)`. In Swift 3, you must have the name of the first (and in this case the only) parameter in the function call. So, your usage of

```
value as NSNumber
```

works, but

```
NSNumber(value: yourNumberValue)
```

works too.

Comment: Ok thanks, that is kind of weird decission from apple but I get it now.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I have taken some assumption here, I have assumed that -

numberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter() // Now it has been renamed to NumberFormatter
celsiusLabel.text I am taking text as optional string just for example you can use label.text for same.

After the above assumption please see below code which will work in Swift 3 -

```
var celsiusValue:Double?
var numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
var text:String?
func updateCelsiusLabel() {

    if let value = celsiusValue {

        //This was the original code (that worked but is) failing after migration due to: Argument labels do not match any available overloads
        text = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: value))!

    }
    else {
        text = "???"
    }
}
```

Hope it help feel free to leave comment in case you have any doubt.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I can't see how your solution solves the problem.
I tried your solution and it is still the same problem. 

The numberFormatter.string function refuses (in your case) to take value because value is not a NSNumber.  


Btw: sorry missed the correct types:  
numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()  
celsiusValue : Double?    

Sorry for the edits but always pushed down enter instead of shift enter

Comment: Ok I have updated the code for taking double value the correct syntax for NSNumber initialisation is same as the above answer i.e - NSNumber(value: value)